# How to take a string as a input in Assembly x64

Tags: linux, assembly, 64-bit, nasm, x86-64

I am writing a program to check if a string is Palindrome or not. I want to take a string as input from user. The string can contain any character ranging from digits to special characters. How can I take input from user. I have tried the following code.

```
global _start
section .bss
    string resb 9

section .text
_start:
    mov rax,0            ;Am I doing this correct ?
    mov rdi,0
    mov rsi,string
    mov rdx,8
    syscall

    xor rax,rax
    mov rdx,[string]
    mov rax,1
    mov rdi,1
    mov rsi,rdx
    mov rdx,8
    syscall

    mov rax,0
    mov rdi,0
    syscall
```

Is the above code correct because when I output the string it shows segmentation fault. The error is

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I am coding in nasm in Linux(Ubuntu 14.04)

Comment: You should show the code with the fault too... also I assume you have a `syscall` instruction and that you are on linux ... but I shouldn't need to assume, you should have told us that too. That said, the reading looks correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For printing you also need to pass the address so `mov rdx, [string]` is wrong, you need `mov rdx, string` or `lea rdx, [string]`. Also, your final syscall is wrong, because that's a `read` again. You probably want `mov rax, 60` to make it `exit`.

See, that's why you should post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Usually Linux requires you to use the exit

```
mov rax, 60
xor rdi, rdi
syscall
```